# Differentiable function strictly concave up $\iff f'$ strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image: show differentiable function $f$ is strictly concave up $\iff f'$ strictly increasing]

I feel like this is false, but I am stumped as to find a counter example. Would $f(x)=x^4$ be a candidate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's true, the curvature of a function is $y''/(1+y'^2)^{3/2}$ as you can see this is positive (concave up) only if $y''$ is positive. $y''$ implies $y'$ increasing.

$y''=0$ at $x=0$ for $x^4$, but $x^4$ is flat at $x=0$ not concave up

Comment: Do you think you could help me with the proof? I'm a little stuck on how even to start.

Comment: that is the proof, pointing out that the formula for the curvature always has the same sign as $y''$. So, for the function to be always concave up (or the curvature to be positive, which is the same), $y''$ must also always be positive. If what you mean is to provide you with a derivation for the formula of the curvature, that is kind of a long answer, but surely you can find it anywhere else

Comment: [Here](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c361.html) for example. There is a chapter about this issue in almost every introductory calculus book.

Comment: I am not sure we are allowed to use the curvature formula..

Comment: To solve the problem you need a precise definition of what it means to be 'concave up'. How would you define it without relating it to curvature?

Comment: We use the definition: Let f be a dierentiable function defined on an interval I. The function f is concave up on I if and only if the graph of f lies below its secant lines on I